# Standard proof that cyclic ordering of edges is preserved under planar graph homotopy?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, graph-theory, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

I have several questions about the following theorem statement:

**Thm:** Let $G = (V, E)$ be a planar graph, and let $\varphi_0 : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$,
$\varphi_1 : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be two planar, piecewise-linear embeddings. The two embeddings induce the same cyclic ordering of edges incident at each vertex of $G$ if and only if there is a homotopy $h: G \times [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ from $\varphi_0$ to $\varphi_1$ such that for all times $t \in [0, 1]$ the function $h_t : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is also a planar, piecewise-linear (PPL) embedding.

**Questions:**

1. Are both directions in fact true?
2. Is there a standard proof for either or both directions, and could someone say where to find these in the literature?
3. I have taken a naive approach to proving the 'if' direction, which I sketch below. Regarding this particular approach:

   a. Is there a simpler way to define the cyclic ordering, and prove the result?

   b. Is the piecewise-linear assumption even necessary? I just need it for my Lemma 1.

Here is my approach to the 'if' direction:

**Def 1:** Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, if $v \in V$ is any vertex then we denote by $I(v) \subseteq E$ the set of edges incident to $v$.

**Def 2:** Let a graph $G = (V, E)$ and PPL embedding $\varphi : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be given. Then by an *ordering radius* we mean a real number $\rho > 0$ such that for all $v \in V$ and $e \in I(v)$ the embedding $\varphi(e)$ of the edge $e$ intersects the boundary of the $\rho$-neighbourhood $B_\rho(\varphi(v))$ of $\varphi(v)$ in exactly one point.

Obviously an ordering radius $\rho$ is so called because it allows us to define a cyclic ordering of edges in $G$ as induced by the given planar embedding $\varphi$. Centred on each vertex $v$ we draw the circle of radius $\rho$. The embedding of each edge $e \in I(v)$ crosses the circle at exactly one point $c_e$. The line from $\varphi(v)$ to $c_e$ makes some angle. Assign this angle to the edge, and order the edges by these angles.

**Lemma 1:** Given $G = (V, E)$ and PPL embedding $\varphi$, an ordering radius exists.

**Pf sketch:** Since $V$ is finite, and since for each $e \in E$ the embedding $\varphi(e)$ is made up of finitely many line segments, it is easy to choose a radius $\rho$ so small that it is an ordering radius.

**Def 3:** Given $G = (V, E)$ and PPL embedding $\varphi$, we define the *maximal ordering radius* $\rho_0(G, \varphi)$ to be the supremum of the set of all ordering radii for $G$ and $\varphi$. By Lemma 1, we know the set in question is nonempty. And it is clearly bounded since the embedding $\varphi$ is bounded. Therefore the supremum exists, and the maximal ordering radius is well-defined.

**Lemma 2:** If $G = (V, E)$ is a planar graph, $\varphi : G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a PPL embedding, and $\rho_0$ is their maximal ordering radius, then for all ordering radii $\rho \leq \rho_0$ on $G, \varphi$, the cyclic ordering induced by $\rho$ is the same as that induced by $\rho_0$.

**Pf:** Suppose to the contrary that there is some ordering radius $\rho_1$ and vertex $v$ whose cyclic ordering under $\rho_1$ is different to that under $\rho_0$. Then there must be some pair of edges $e, e' \in I(v)$ whose order inverts. Let $\theta : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ give the angle of edge $e$ as we continuously deform the circle of radius $\rho_0$ around $\varphi(v)$ to that of radius $\rho_1$, and likewise define $\theta'$ for edge $e'$. By the intermediate value theorem, the graphs of the functions $\theta, \theta'$ must intersect. This corresponds to a point where the embeddings $\varphi(e)$ and $\varphi(e')$ intersect, and so contradicts planarity of the embedding $\varphi$. QED

**Def 4:** Now, based on Lemma 2 it makes sense to define *the cyclic ordering of $G$ under $\varphi$* to be that induced by the maximal ordering radius for $G$, $\varphi$.

Finally, we can prove the theorem.

**Pf sketch:** The key idea is the same as in the proof of Lemma 2. If the cyclic orderings induced by $\varphi_0$ and $\varphi_1$ differed for some vertex $v$, then over the homotopy $h$ we would find some time $t$ at which $h_t$ was not planar. We would do this by applying the IVT to the functions giving the angles of the edges in $I(v)$ as we deform, exactly as in the proof of Lemma 2.

**EDIT:** Based on initial comments, rewrote the question for clarity and future usefulness.

Comment: In the statement of the theorem, the "if and only if" should be just "if".

Comment: @Allen: Do you have a counterexample for the converse? I would say that "if and only if" is fine...

Comment: For examples where "only if" fails, start with a graph in ${\mathbb R}^2$ whose complement is not connected, then add a point at infinity to get a graph in $S^2={\mathbb R}^2\cup\{\infty\}$. For each complementary component of this graph in $S^2$, if one deletes a point from this component, one obtains an embedding of the graph in ${\mathbb R}^2$ with the same cyclic orderings at vertices, but the various embeddings obtained this way are not homotopic in the sense defined in the question. (This notion of "homotopy" is usually called "isotopy".)

Comment: The "only if" direction also fails if the graph itself is disconnected and has at least one cycle.